# jquery regexp selector

Tags: jquery

I have a simple example:

```
<li id="item0" class="test"> 
    .....
<li id="item10" class="test">
```

How to remove class "test" from all elements this id =~ "#item\d{1,}" using jquery ?

Comment: For this case, the attribute "starts with" selector should be fine, but if you are wanting to use more complicated regular expressions in your selectors, check out this extension: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get just those IDs:

```
$('li[id^="item"]').removeClass('test');
```

Comment: Good call. Beat me by a minute or so.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(youritem).removeClass('test');
```

Comment: I don't think removeAttr would work.  removeClass is what you want.

Comment: You should use removeClass anyway :D

Comment: I think the question is how to use the regex as a selector, not how to remove the class...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need a ^= selector on the element.

```
$('li[id^=item]').removeClass('test');
```

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/3Rudp/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex expressions in your jQuery selectors, check out this plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

In this context it would be something like:

```
$('.test:regex(id, ^item([0-9]+)$)').removeClass('test');
```

[See jsFiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/FmsYN/)